# How can i pick the list in the dropdown from this given code?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

Sorry for the confusion created by my provided code. I am actually trying to automate the dropdown here but i just know about how to do it with the help of Select class but not sure how it is going on. Please look into the below attached image and suggest me how to pick this type of dropdown.

=============================================================================[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTszw.png

Comment: it'd be better if you could post a inflated snapshot of the dropdown; because it's hard to understand which is a dropdown and which are its options

Comment: Please read [ask] and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc.

Comment: A lot of those `<li>`s are open. You might want to add a couple of `</li>`s

Answer (score 0):

It isnt select so you can't use Select Class in Selenium.

Just use driver.findElement with xpath:

`//div[contains(@class,'dropdown-menu']/ul/li/a[.='your_option_value']`

and simply click() on it.

Example xpath for your option "Know My Numbers":

`//div[contains(@class,'dropdown-menu']/ul/li/a[.='Know My Numbers']`

Answer (score 0):

You can first click on the dropdown element to expand as below:

```
 driver.findElement(By.cassSelctor("div#dropdown-menu.ng-scope"));
```

and then select any of the options using below code:

```
  driver.findElement(By.cassSelctor("div#dropdown-menu.ng-scope ul li:nth-child(i) a"));

  //here i is your index no of option you want to select from the dropdown.
```